# Select Statement to Retrieve Smoothed Timestamps

Tags: sql-server, select, timestamp

I need to select data from this table [dbo].[table] in SQL Server below. However, I need to select intervals of 30 minutes. I cannot use WITH statements because Tibco Spotfire is rejecting all With Statements for unknown reasons.

```
ID DateTime         Value
-----------------------------
ID1 2022-04-30 03:57:30 100    
ID1 2022-04-30 04:02:30 110
ID1 2022-04-30 04:07:30 120
ID1 2022-04-30 04:12:34 130
ID1 2022-04-30 04:17:34 140
ID1 2022-04-30 04:22:33 150
ID1 2022-04-30 04:27:33 160
ID1 2022-04-30 04:32:30 170
```

Is there a way to retrieve the desired dataframe, so the timestamps have 30 minute intervals? I'm not too concerned on if `value` is averaged between two timestamps or not (i.e. averaging the first two records would be 105).

```
ID DateTime         Value
-----------------------------
ID1 2022-04-30 04:00:00 105    
ID1 2022-04-30 04:30:00 165
```

**OR**

```
ID DateTime         Value
-----------------------------
ID1 2022-04-30 03:00:00 100    
ID1 2022-04-30 04:30:00 170
```

Comment: Why can't you use WITH statements (called CTE's)?

Comment: @squillman The dashboard used is rejecting WITH statements for unknown reasons

Comment: What if you created a view that contains the CTE and let Spotfire pull from the view?

Comment: Explain how 105 appears in the first row. Your calculation seems to be "flexible" with regard to which rows are included in which 30 min period. Shouldn't you be using a calculation based on all the rows within a period?

Comment: @squillman That would work

Comment: @SMor Taking an average of the first two rows 100 + 110 / 2 = 105

Comment: What about rounding the timestamps to the nearest 30 minute interval?

Comment: @jw11432 How do I do that?

Comment: This appears to work: `dateadd(minute, datediff(minute,0,[YourDate]) / 30 * 30, 0)`